# Misbehaving context menu (mvvm)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, contextmenu

I've put together what I thought was a context menu in an MVVM setting (I'm using WPF with XAML and C#, using MVVM). Only it's not working, which is why I'm here. I'm getting nothing in my context menu.

The XAML is supposed to call an ICommand in the code behind (or Relay Command since I'm using micro MVVM - same thing basically).

The first thing was to set up an object which the XAML could get the two needed values from - the Header and the Command. The item in question looks like this:

```
class ContextMenuVM : ObservableObject
{
    public string Displayname { get; set; }
    public RelayCommand ContextMenuCommand { get; set; }
}
```

So, rather simple there. These will be used for the bindings in the menu.

The view model here is called 'CharacterListViewModel' and contains an ObservableCollection if these ContextMenuVM objects. That looks like this:

```
private ObservableCollection<ContextMenuVM> _sceneAddMenu = new ObservableCollection<ContextMenuVM>();
public ObservableCollection<ContextMenuVM> SceneAddMenu
{
    get { return _sceneAddMenu; }
    set
    {
        if (_sceneAddMenu != value)
        {
            _sceneAddMenu = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SceneAddMenu");
        }
    }
}
```

The ObservableCollection is populated, as follows:

```
foreach (Scene s in Database.Instance.Scenes)
{
    SceneAddMenu.Add(new ContextMenuVM()
    {
        Displayname = s.SceneName, ContextMenuCommand = new RelayCommand(
        () =>
            {
            MessageBox.Show("Clicked");
            })
    });                            
}
```

Just a test at the moment, but I can say through use of break points that SceneAddMenu contains four items after this code is run (as I would expect).

Well, that's kind of the background code. I suspect it works, although clearly something is broken. My suspicion is the XAML.

The context menu code itself is here:

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="CharacterMenu" ItemsSource="{Binding SceneAddMenu}">
    <ContextMenu.ItemTemplate >
        <DataTemplate DataType="MenuItem">
            <MenuItem Header="Edit" Command="{Binding ContextMenuCommand}"></MenuItem>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ContextMenu.ItemTemplate>
</ContextMenu>
```

Ah, so the obvious problem would be that the data context is not properly set up. Well that's not the case because this context menu replaces another one which utilised a command in the view model (and that worked), so my assumption is that the view model is okay.

For the record, the previous context menu, which works, looked like this:

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="CharacterMenu">
    <MenuItem Header="Edit" Command="{Binding EditCharacter}"/>
</ContextMenu>
```

And if I put that back in, it works. Since it has a binding to the view model, that would suggest that the data context is not the problem.

The Context menu itself is referenced a little later, like this:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="3" ContextMenu="{StaticResource CharacterMenu}">
```

But since that was also in before with the previous menu (i.e. when it worked), I only include it for completion's sake.

So the SceneAddMenu object (ObservableCollection) is populated. That seems to be fine. Somewhere between the XAML and the view model there must be a problem though. If I put a break point in the 'get' for SceneAddMenu and then right click on the item in question, the break point does not activate.

I am at a bit of a loss on this one. It's my first time creating a context menu using the MVVM method, so it's possible I missed out a step somewhere.

If you read all of this, thanks a lot. If I missed out any information, please let me know.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me.  Not sure why yours does not.

Comment: DId you try the solution I proposed or what happened?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't add a `MenuItem` to the `ItemTemplate` of a `ContextMenu`. You should define an `ItemContainerStyle` and bind to the `Displayname` and `ContextMenuCommand` properties of your class:

```
<ContextMenu x:Key="CharacterMenu" ItemsSource="{Binding SceneAddMenu}">
    <ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Displayname}" />
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding ContextMenuCommand} " />
        </Style>
    </ContextMenu.ItemContainerStyle>
</ContextMenu>
```